# User-defined literals without underscore

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, user-defined-literals

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal#Literal_operators) it is possible to define a literal using

```
CSomeClass operator ""s(const char* literal, size_t size);
```

Now after reading the paragraph I think it should be also possible to define

```
CSomeClass operator ""r(const char* literal, size_t size);
```

(note the `r` ud-suffix instead of `s`)

Overloading `s` just gives the clang warning

```
warning: user-defined literal suffixes not starting with '_' are reserved [-Wuser-defined-literals]
```

which I can't really understand as I'm compiling with `-std=c++14`. Overloading `r` gives

```
error: invalid suffix on literal; C++11 requires a space between literal and identifier [-Wreserved-user-defined-literal]
warning: user-defined literal suffixes not starting with '_' are reserved; no literal will invoke this operator [-Wuser-defined-literals]
```

which seems even less accountable to me.

Why does clang emit these warnings/errors and how can I make the `r` ud-suffix valid.

Comment: What part of the warning don't you understand? It says your literal has to start with `_`. The reference you link to says the same. You can't declare one called `r`, but you can declare one called `_r`.

Comment: Reading the reference I understood that since c++14 one can overload without the underscore.

Comment: OK, I can see how the wording of that reference might imply that the restriction only applied to the form with a space, not the new C++14 form. The standard's quite clear though: "Literal suffix identifiers that do not start with an underscore are reserved for future standardization."

Comment: @Mike Seymour cppreference edited to stress that point

Comment: Are you compiling `s` with C++14 and `r` with C++11?  I guess I'm confused about the warning on one and the error on the other.  I do remember at one point the "" and the identifier were required to touch with no intervening space.  Then it was relaxed.  I can't remember if that was C++14 or a DR on C++11..  I'll check but I'm pretty sure his was a DR against C++11.

Comment: There is something - and this gets back to why the lack of `_` is discouraged for user-space code.  An implementation (and the standard) is allowed to use suffixes without an underscore.  Such a suffix, say `r`, will shadow the literal operator for that same suffix defined by the user.  Does anyone know if clang or libc uses `r`?  That would do it.

Comment: @emsr nope, both are compiled in c++14 mode

Answer (score 14, accepted):

User-defined literals must begin with the underscore _: the suffixes that do not begin with the underscore are reserved for the literal operators provided by the standard library.

Comment: Hm ok.. Where does it actually say that the second alternative (marked with `since C++14`) is reserved for the standard library (be it on the site or in the standard)?

Comment: @Uroc327 In the definition for `ud-suffix`.

Comment: In the event that future C++ adds a e.g. a "qqz" literal suffix with some meaning, is it intended that programmers using today's compilers should be allowed to write code which, when run on a compiler without "qqz", would define "qqz" in the same fashion as the future standard does?