# C++ std Chrono - How did they manage to let us declare values as 1s, 1000ms, etc?

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

Looking at C++ Core Guidelines as a new C++ Programmer, and seeing this kind of declaration is very weird to me coming from a C# background.

Example taken [here](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#p8-dont-leak-any-resources:%7E:text=The%20function%20can%20also%20be%20written%20in%20such%20a%20way%20that%20it%20will%20accept%20any%20time%20duration%20unit.).

```
void use()
{
    blink_led(2s);
    blink_led(1500ms);
}
```

Would someone like to explain or give me pointers to understand what's going on?

Thanks!

Comment: It's called "User-defined literals" and its been around since C++11, see here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal

Comment: Note that user-defined-literals need to start with an underscore, whereas literals in the std namespace don't. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29017344/user-defined-literals-without-underscore

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast reponse I will check this out!