# C++ Timer suggestions?

Tags: c++, timer, countdown

I'm trying to create a timer for fun. I'm running into the trouble of the computer being too fast for counting every second; therefore it prints " cout << "the time" << theTime << endl; " like 10 times, but I want it to only print once. Any suggestions to what I should do or looking into? Thanks.

just thought of a potential solution: using the difftime to check if the new time is different from previous

```
    void activateTimer(int Hours)
{
    double seconds;
    //current time
    //figure out what each lines does http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/gmtime/
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * ptm;
    time(&rawtime);
    ptm = localtime(&rawtime);


    cout << "The current time is: " << (ptm->tm_hour - 12) << ":" << (ptm->tm_min)<<endl; //time hour time minute
    cout << "The stop time is:" << (ptm->tm_hour - 12 + Hours) << ":" << (ptm->tm_min)<<endl;
    cout << "Commencing countdown timer." << endl;
    while ((ptm->tm_hour - 12) != ((ptm->tm_hour) + (Hours)))   //checking if the hours match
    {
        //declaration
        time_t rawtime;  //calling the library raw time
        struct tm * ptm; //strcuture of 7 things tm_sec, tm_min, tm_hour, pointed by ptm
        time(&rawtime); //time=rawtime(null)
        ptm = localtime(&rawtime); 

        if (ptm->tm_sec == 59 || ptm->tm_sec == 60 || ptm->tm_sec == 61)
        {
            //intializiation
            int theTime = ((ptm->tm_hour - 12 + Hours) * 60) + (ptm->tm_min);
            cout << "the time" << theTime << endl;


        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your loop probably executes to fast to get different values.

Comment: You have suggested the solution yourself - why don't you try it?

Comment: You should consider [adding a delay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158585/how-do-you-add-a-timed-delay-to-a-c-program) to your loop to slow down the execution.

Comment: I propose you use [std::chrono](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono)