# Delay in CodeWarrior

Tags: c++, arduino, delay

I am new to trying to write anything. While I can read what's happening most of the time, I have no idea how to build a delay. In Arduino I have used delays but it doesn't seem to work the same here.
I have been searching the internet trying to find something that will work, but with no luck. I think I could make something work but I don't know how to add more '#includes' either. Currently I have-

```
#include <xbee_config.h>
#include <types.h>
#include <utils.h>
#include <xbee/atcmd.h>
```

I have the general idea of what is needed but now idea how to write it.  I'm turning on an LED that I need delayed before turning off.

```
gpio_set(LED1, 1);      //Turn on LED
**Delay here!!!!**
gpio_set(LED1, 0);      //Turn off LED
```

My first thought is building a void_delay function that will increment a counter until x time is reached, then return to the program. I know that's not the best way as it will be keeping the program from other tasks while counting, but it should work for my purpose. The problem, I have no idea how to write that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you add a timed delay to a C++ program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158585/how-do-you-add-a-timed-delay-to-a-c-program)

Comment: That is one that I had found, but I don’t think it is applicable. I tried the sleep() functions and kept getting sintax errors. I think the CodeWarrior platform may be different but I am not certain. It also could be that don’t have the #include (library’s?) that are noted in that post. I have not found the details of how to include more yet, but I know that has to be something in the manual I just haven’t found yet.

Answer (score 0):

In c++ you can use [`Sleep(milliseconds)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep?redirectedfrom=MSDN) you only have to include `<windows.h>`.
Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
cout << "Before delay" <<endl;
    Sleep(5000);
cout << "After delay" <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, so by adding the windows.h I would be able to use the sleep function correct?

Comment: I'm having trouble adding the windows.h.