# Print each number from 1 to 10 on the cleared screen with some time between them

Tags: c++

I want to print each number from 1 to 10 on the cleared screen with some time between them. I tried this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
  {
    cout << i;
    system("cls");
    for(int j = 1; j <= 10000000; j++)
        continue;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

But it doesn't work as intended, instead:

[image]

How to get what I actually wish?

Comment: should be `clear` not `cls`

Comment: @sebastian Well, now those `not found`'s disappeared, but still I get `12345678910` on the same screen...

Comment: I want something like *seconds* in watch

Comment: Does this answer your question regarding time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158585/how-do-you-add-a-timed-delay-to-a-c-program/158614

Comment: Note that you try to clear the screen as soon as you display `i`.I am surprised you can see anything.

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486289/how-can-i-clear-console in regard to clearing the screen. You should really learn how to search things on the internet.